# show mysql myisam locks

Tags: mysql

when dropping or renaming a table with myisam storage engine, I realize that it's waiting for table metadata lock, however, show full processlist doesn't reveal the offending query.  any idea?

```
| 462 | root | xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:54658 | mydb | Sleep   | 1162 |                                 | NULL                                                 |
| 465 | root | localhost           | mydb | Query   |    0 | NULL                            | show full processlist                                |
| 466 | root | localhost           | mydb | Query   |  125 | Waiting for table metadata lock | alter table mytable rename to mytable_junk |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 5.5, [there is a bug report on it](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59134).

If fact, [click here for an explanation of metadata locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/metadata-locking.html). It is meant to protect tables from getting DDL executed against it while in the middle of a transaction.

What seems strange is that you are getting this on a MyISAM table.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Our mysql is at 5.5.25a. and myisam tables somehow get stuck with a metadata lock. I tried `set global lock_wait_timeout=100;` but that did not work. The only way I managed to kill the lock was to restart the mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to convert a table collation as follows:

```
 alter table xxx convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I then noticed that on the "show full processlist" the request was freeze on the following state "Waiting for table metadata lock"

To resolve the issue, I opened another console in parallel and launched the following SQL command :

```
flush tables
```

Regards